# Caching XmlSerializer in AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net

To work around the [XmlSerializer memory leak thing](https://web.archive.org/web/20151115131944/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/net-memory-leak-xmlserializing-your-way-to-a-memory-leak.aspx) I created this:

```
public static class XmlSerializerCache
{
    public static XmlSerializer GetXmlSerializer(Type type, XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot)
    {
        var cache = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var key = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "CachedXmlSerializer:{0}:{1}", type, xmlRoot.ElementName);

        var serializer = cache.GetData(key) as XmlSerializer;
        if (serializer == null)
        {
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, xmlRoot);
            cache.SetData(key, serializer);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, the generated assemblies get unloaded as soon as the AppDomain gets unloaded. So I thought I can use the AppDomain Cache to cache my serializers.

Is this approach a good one? Or at least a "Leak-Safe" one?

Comment: Gotta be honest, I've never actually used that particular `XmlSerializer` constructor overload that doesn't cache.

Comment: Do you actually have multiple AppDomains in your application? If not, this code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'd say I have only one AppDomain. (I don't explicitly use more than one.)

Comment: Can this be used in a WCF generated client reference?

Answer (score 1):

According the work around section in the [kb article](https://web.archive.org/web/20070102071100/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/886385/en-us) mentioned in the [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/net-memory-leak-xmlserializing-your-way-to-a-memory-leak.aspx) entry, your solution looks correct.